# Does apt-get purge remove reverse dependencies?

Tags: apt

Suppose we `sudo apt-get purge mypackage`.
If `mypackage`, which is a dependency of `yourpackage`, is installed at the time that we purge `mypackage`, is `mypackage` also removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple test will answers you:

```
$ apt-cache depends vim
vim
  Depends: vim-common
  Depends: vim-runtime
  Depends: libacl1
  Depends: libc6
      ......
```

Now as you can see the package vim depends on vim-common. So let's try remove the package `vim-common`:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove vim-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-minimal vim vim-common vim-tiny
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
After this operation, 3,268 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Take a look on the line:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   ubuntu-minimal vim vim-common vim-tiny
```

So as a conclusion removing a package will cause to remove all packages that depend on it.

Comment: Yes , but apt-get remove vim will not remove vim-common. Do apt-get autoremove after you deinstall, it will remove unneeded packages. Purge removes the configuration of packages.

Comment: @UweBurger Please read the question again, the OP asks for reverse dependencies

Answer (score 0):

It is good to check with --dry-run what will happen to prevent accidental damage.

```
apt purge vim-common --dry-run
```